# using BackPress method to release MediaPlayer class problem

Tags: java, android-studio, android-mediaplayer, onbackpressed

the app works fine my only problem is I don't want to put a stop button rather I want the default backPress to stop and release MediaPlayer, so I added this:

```
public void onBackPressed(){
            super.onStop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
```

it works 1 time but pressing it again would crash the app

```
2020-07-10 16:23:54.943 6315-6315/com.example.schoolwork E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.schoolwork, PID: 6315
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition(Native Method)
    at com.example.schoolwork.play_bidlisiw1.changeSeekbar(play_bidlisiw1.java:63)
    at com.example.schoolwork.play_bidlisiw1.access$200(Play_bidlisiw1.java:12)
    at com.example.schoolwork.play_bidlisiw1$3.run(play_bidlisiw1.java:69)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
```

I am a beginner in coding java and new at using android studio. I am hoping anyone can teach me.
Thank you for your advice.

```
public class ark_play_bidlisiw1 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
private Button btnFor, btnBack, btnPlay;
private SeekBar seekBar;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private Runnable runnable;
private Handler handler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.play_bidlisiw1);
    btnPlay = findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
    btnBack = findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
    btnFor = findViewById(R.id.btnFor);
    handler = new Handler();
    seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bidlisiw1);
    btnFor.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnBack.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
            mediaPlayer.start();
            changeSeekbar();
        }
    });
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
            if(b){
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(i);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
}

private void changeSeekbar() {
    seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());

    if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                changeSeekbar();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnPlay:
            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                btnPlay.setText(">");
            }else {
                mediaPlayer.start();
                btnPlay.setText("||");
                changeSeekbar();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.btnFor:
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()+5000);
            break;
        case R.id.btnBack:
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()-5000);
            break;
    }
}
public void onBackPressed(){
    super.onStop();
    mediaPlayer.release();

}
```

}

Comment: Where is your closing on for the onBackPressed method ?

Comment: }? ITS THERE SORRY MISSED ON THE COPY

Comment: Are you sure mediaPlayer is not null when you try to release it? add null check before it

Comment: hahaha how do i null it? heheh im realy a noob at this dont have any  backgound in programing hope you can teach me thanks...:D